# react-window resetAfterIndex does not maintain the column's state

Tags: reactjs, react-window

I was trying to add a component that has it's own state into the row, but I could not remain the component's state when I trigger the `toggle()` which consist of the `resetAfterIndex()`. From my understanding, that is the behaviour of `resetAfterIndex()` of react-window.

Is there a way where I can update the row's height while maintaining the component's state?

Source code: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-window-custom-row-expand-b45hv)

**P.S:** If possible I would like to prevent parent hold the component's state, due to unknown number of component that I need to add into a row